# Angular app is compiling but shows blank white screen. Network tab shows 404 errors

Tags: json, angular, bootstrap-4, http-status-code-404, bootstrap-5

I need help, I get a blank screen on browser after debugging my angular 15 app. There are no problems, no errors in detected in the workspace. However, when I open *Network tab in DevTools* I notice config.js, styles.css, app(zone.js) get **404** status. I am not sure where the code is gone wrong underneath

app.module.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './pages/contact/contact.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './components/navigation/navigation.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbCollapseModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
/*Plus all your other modules*/


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbCollapseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbCollapseModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NavigationComponent } from './components/navigation/navigation.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';

@Component  ({  
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule], 
  declarations: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
}) 
export class AppModule {}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "test-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/test-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "test-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "test-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "test-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that you have two `AppModule`s. And only one has a `bootstrap` element. Which `AppModule` are you bootstrapping (possibly in main.ts file)?

Answer (score 0):

In app.module.ts, you have not specified which component should be bootstrapped